# (JQuery) Fancybox launch only using classes?

Tags: jquery, video, fancybox

I'm trying to get a video list w/ thumbnails working with Fancybox - the problem is that it seems each link uses classes to launch the fancybox

What if i want this to be more dynamic, a list of video links and each one opens a new video? I shouldnt have to create a new click function defintion for each one do i?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
```

$(".fancyvideo5").click(function () {
                $.fancybox({
                    'padding': 0,
                    'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
                    'autoDimensions': false,
                    'content': 'myConent',
                    'onComplete': function () { $("#fancybox-inner").css({ 'overflow': 'hidden' }); },
                    'onClosed': function () { $("#fancybox-inner").empty(); }
                });
                return false;
            }); // fancyvideo

and the body will have something like:

```
<ul>

    <li>
        <a title="test" href="javascript:;" class="fancyvideo5"><img  src="thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
    </li>                                                                              

</ul>
```

id like to have something like

```
<a title="test" href="javascript:openVideo(1);" class="fancyvideo5"><img  src="thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
```

So i can pass the video information and call the function instead of everything on document ready.

Thanks

Comment: Actually i might have found the answer here:
[jQuery Fancybox and Flowplayer Integration](http://www.burconsult.com/tutorials/fp2/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used fancybox in awhile, but if I remember correctly you can use one fancybox function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(a.fancyvideo).fancybox(
         //settings
));
```

Then, for you links

```
<a href="#video" class="fancyvideo" />
<a href="#video2" class="fancyvideo" />
<a href="#video3" class="fancyvideo" />
<a href="#video4" class="fancyvideo" />
```

and

```
<div id="video" style="display: none;"> 
//insert embed code here
</div>
<div id="video2" style="display: none;"> 
//insert embed code here
</div>

<div id="video3" style="display: none;"> 
//insert embed code here
</div>

<div id="video4" style="display: none;"> 
//insert embed code here
</div>
```

Comment: that moves the embed code into the div doesnt it? which is great - out of the 'content', i think.  but what if i want many videos within the list? how can i differentiate between teh links and launch the correct video

Comment: You just have multiple divs each with their own embedded content. Then multiple links which each href="#divId" . Get it?

Comment: Ah i see - wouldnt this get cumbersome if there were dozens+ of videos?